# What exactly is Hardware Acceleration?

Tags: parallel-computing, vectorization

I'm able to find many definitions and notions to this term including,

- Implementing the algorithm (or part of it) in hardware :- Instructions like FMAD; FPGAs
- Parallelizing the algorithm at the hardware level :- SIMD, GPU etc.

So, what exactly is Hardware Acceleration ?

I would like to understand the meaning of the word to not sound ambiguous in technical discussions.

Answer (score 3):

Hardware acceleration means any code run on specialized hardware, as opposed to software run on general purpose CPUs such as standard x86 processors on your PC.

I suppose the term is inherently ambiguous (e.g. does [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) count as hardware acceleration?), and probably means different specific things in different industries. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_acceleration) is a good starting point. As a member of the scientific computing community, when I hear "hardware acceleration" I instantly think [GPU acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units) of numerical algorithms, and my second thought is FPGA numerical implementations. But for example, [hardware implementations of video codecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC_products_and_implementations#Prominent_hardware_implementations) can also be considered hardware acceleration.